# How to make oozie job get triggered when a success file is present in aws S3

Tags: xml, hadoop, amazon-s3, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am working with oozie to perform a HDFS data transfer operation, the requirement is to trigger oozie workflow job whenever there is data available in aws S3 bucket. I am thinking of keeping a success file along with data files in my S3 bucket, but I am not sure, how to make oozie coordinator periodically read from S3 to check if the success file is available or not.
It would be great, if somebody can provide the sample coordinator.xml for the same.

Comment: You can invoke the oozie REST API to start the job, from a AWS Lambda trigger which will be invoked upon s3 upload event

Comment: How to create a oozie REST api for a job currently running on time based coordinator?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try out the below :-

```
<coordinator-app name="FILE_CHECK" frequency="1440" start="2017-04-17T00:00Z" end="2018-04-17T00:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">

<datasets>
      <dataset name="datafile" frequency="60" initial-instance="2017-04-16T00:00Z" timezone="UTC">
         <uri-template>s3n://mybucket/a/b/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}</uri-template>
         <done-flag><flag to check></done-flag>
      </dataset>
   </datasets>
   <input-events>
      <data-in name="coorddatafile" dataset="datafile">
          <instance>${coord:current(0)}</start-instance>
      </data-in>
   </input-events>
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path><workflow_path></app-path>
          <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>fileDirectory</name>
                    <value>${coord:dataIn('coorddatafile')}</value>
                </property>
          </configuration>
      </workflow>
   </action>     
</coordinator-app>
```

You can also refer : -https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Getting-Oozie-Coordinator-datasets-working-with-S3-after-a-lost/td-p/27233

Comment: It will check for the existence of the flag and then it will trigger the job.

Comment: What is the content of a flag, in some of the examples it is a file (.bat file).

Comment: In many scenarios it is a _SUCCESS file ( can be 0 byte also )  which is created by the another hadoop process on successful completion of the job before. The <done-flag> tag checks the presence of the file in the folder. Content does not matter.

Comment: for example : <done-flag>success.bat</done-flag>
So, is it like when this file is present, trigger the job?

Also, another doubt is the significance of uri-template. In most of the examples I have seen, the uri-template is present in the directory format ending with $year/$month/$day.
1.) Can't it be a simple file like : <uri-template>s3://mybucket/my_file.csv</uri-template>?
2.) If I only need a trigger as a success file(success.bat) in s3, can uri-template be empty in this scenario and done-flag can have complete s3 file address?

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely correct, when the file is present ,trigger the job. 
Many examples are available coz they poll the particular HDFS directory at different times.Every day /hour it should poll that particular hour/day directory for the file.
The <uri-template> is basically the location for the oozie to poll for the existence of the file, so empty string won't help.
For eg:-
<uri-template>s3://mybucket</uri-template>
<done-flag>my_file.csv</done-flag>

Comment: Thanks. Also why is input-events required? In my current coordinator.xml, I am not using it, and when checking oozie -info with job_id of coordinator, it is showing successful runs of jobs. But, as in my workflow.xml, I have just simply sent an email, whenever it is triggered, but I have not received any email, is it because of not using the <input-events>, that the workflow is not at all running?

Comment: Yeah, you need to include it.The Input events of a coordinator application specify the input conditions that are required in order to execute a coordinator action.

In the current specification input events are restricted to dataset instances availability.

Comment: @DeepanRam What are the configuration has to be done so that oozie is configured to read s3 bucket?

Comment: @AkashTantri you need to specify the s3 location with s3://n prefix instead of hdfs location